# how to get number out of an array key

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array:

```
Array
(
    [Ingredient 1 Amount] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
        )

    [Ingredient 1] => Array
        (
            [0] => lemon  juice (t fresh-squeezed)
        )

    [Ingredient 2 Amount] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
        )

    [Ingredient 2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1/2 cups peeled and diced potatoes
        )

    [Ingredient 3 Amount] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1/3
        )

    [Ingredient 3 Size] => Array
        (
            [0] => cup
        )

    [Ingredient 3] => Array
        (
            [0] => diced celery
        )

    [Ingredient 4 Amount] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1/3
        )

    [Ingredient 4 Size] => Array
        (
            [0] => cup
        )

    [Ingredient 4] => Array
        (
            [0] => finely chopped onion
        )

    [Ingredient 5 Amount] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
        )

    [Ingredient 5 Size] => Array
        (
            [0] => tablespoons
        )

    [Ingredient 5] => Array
        (
            [0] => pickles
        )

)
```

Each ingredient set consists of Amount, Size and just the Default. There may be one of each or there may be some missing, so I can't just count the array and divide by 3. I need to know how many ingredient sets are in the array. This is shown by the last ingredient set, so in this case I would want the number "5". How would I go about getting that?

--EDIT--

The array is being built from custom post fields in wordpress. It's what I get back from

```
$post_meta = get_post_meta($id);
```

Comment: "*Each ingredient set consists of Amount, Size and just the Default.*" — Where are these defined? Could you clarify?

Comment: Is restructuring your array an option? If so can you please post your code that creates the array.

Comment: You will need to post the code for the `get_post_meta()` function as that is what needs changing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I've mentioned in my comments restructuring your array would be far better, as your current structure isn't helpful for what you want to do. However, assuming that isn't an option this is what to do:

```
$key = end(array_keys($array));
$num = substr($key, 11);
```

You can see an example of this in work [here on eval.in](https://eval.in/128960).

---

This will work if the last key won't always be the one you want:

```
$keyArr = array_keys($array);
$keyRev = array_reverse($keyArr);
foreach($keyRev as $key) {
  if(stripos($key, 'amount') === FALSE && stripos($key, 'size') === FALSE) {
    $num = substr($key, 11);
    break;
  }
}

echo $num;
```

You can see an example of this in work [here on eval.in](https://eval.in/128967).

Comment: @user3455992 as you're using wordpress it might be hard to change the structure. Those two lines will do what you need

Comment: unfortunately the array isn't guaranteed to end with the default ingredient. That may even be missing. It could end with Ingredient Amount, or Ingredient Size.

Comment: @user3455992 Updated to find the last one that is Ingredient, ignoring Amount and Size.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you should re-structure you're array. It is not optimised.

Try something along the lines of (this is psuedo code to give the idea)

```
[Ingredient 1] => Array
    (
        [type] => lemon  juice (t fresh-squeezed),
        [Amount] => lemon  juice (t fresh-squeezed),
        [Size] => lemon  juice (t fresh-squeezed)

 )
```

Comment: thx farnabaz.. i'm new to stackoverflow and need to have a look how to properly indent a post :/

Answer (score 0):

you can find maximum like this

```
$max = 0;
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
   if(intval(str_replace("Ingredient ", "", $key)) > $max) {
      $max = intval(str_replace("Ingredient ", "", $key));
   }
}
```

**NOTICE:** as Styphon mentioned in comments  if you want to get last element number, it's not necessary to loop through whole array, only process last element

Comment: I like this one the best so far. Will it work if it ends in Ingredient Amount or Ingredient Size as well? Or does it have to end in Ingredient like the answer above?

Comment: @Styphon but what if array indexes are not sorted in increasing order?

Comment: @Farnabaz There's no indication that they aren't. Everything the OP has given says they are, so until told otherwise I assume they are. He specifically asked for the last one in the array, not the highest value key.

Comment: @Styphon so if they are sorted you completely right

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = array(
    array(['ingediant1'] => 
        array(
            'amount' => 1, 
            'description' => 'whatever'
            )
        )
);
$amount = 0;
foreach ($a as $ingediant => $info) {
    $amount += $info['amount'];
}
```

If you'd restructure your array to something like I did, you should be able to get the total amount of ingredients easy.

Comment: Adding some explanation will help OP understand better.